# ImportError: cannot import name 'ExifTags' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

when trying to convert file to .exe using pyinstaller, when opening the .exe file this error appears, what can it be?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ExifTags' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\-\ApptData\Local\Temp\_MEI116322\PIL\__init__.pyc)
```

Comment: install auto-py-to-exe as well, then in command prompt type auto-py-to-exe and then fill out the required details and click run.

Comment: Can you add a [mre] and include which library you are using (which command did you use to install it)? Possibly show the (relevant) output of `python -m pip freeze` as well.

Answer (score 0):

PIL and Pillow currently cannot co-exist in the same environment. If you want to use Pillow, remove PIL first.

Maybe if you add ExifTags as a hidden import argument, it will work.

`pyinstaller --hidden-import="PIL.ExifTags" file.py`

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain why this works and/or why this is necessary? If so, please add that to your answer, which would make it an (even) more valuable answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).